# Appending Variable to property in Type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is there a way to append a variable to an existing property on a Type?
I need to append the `IMGPATH`variable with the `poster_path` prop to get the correct url for the image, but since I need to define the property correctly, I'm unsure of how to do this.

There are no errors in my Movie component, but when I render it in the App.tsx, I get an error of:

```
Type '{ key: any; src: any; title: any; overview: any; vote_average: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MovieType'.
Property 'src' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MovieType'
```

Is there a better way to approach this?

Here is the App Component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Movie from './components/Movie';

const APIURL =
    'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=04c35731a5ee918f014970082a0088b1&page=1';

export default function App() {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState<any[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(APIURL);
            setMovies(result.data.results);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {movies.map((movie) => (
                <Movie
                    key={movie.id}
                    src={movie.poster_path}
                    title={movie.title}
                    overview={movie.overview}
                    vote_average={movie.vote_average}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is my Movie Component

```
import React from 'react';

const IMGPATH = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280';

type MovieType = {
    id?: string;
    title: string;
    overview: string;
    poster_path: string;
    vote_average: number;
};

const Movie = ({ id, title, overview, vote_average, poster_path }: MovieType) => {
    return (
        <div key={id}>
            <img src={IMGPATH + poster_path} alt={title} />
            <div>{title}</div>
            <div>{overview}</div>
            <div>{vote_average}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Movie;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please share the app.tsx code

Comment: looks like you are passing src to movie from outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code you are passing those props to movie

```
           <Movie
                key={movie.id}
                src={movie.poster_path}
                title={movie.title}
                overview={movie.overview}
                vote_average={movie.vote_average}
            />
```

but the signature of your movie component is a MovieType so the src props should be added to MovieType

```
type MovieType = {
    id?: string;
    src: string;
    title: string;
    overview: string;
    poster_path: string;
    vote_average: number;
};
```

or removed from outside

```
       <Movie
            key={movie.id}
            title={movie.title}
            overview={movie.overview}
            vote_average={movie.vote_average}
        />
```